# Is it possible to add description on an existing link in google streetviewpanorama?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I just started using V3. I have setup google streetviewpanorama and i want to add description on the link(the arrow seen on streetview)..what are the possible ways to handle this?
any answer will be much appreciated..

Comment: You can read `Custom Street View panoramas` [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-custom-simple) and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-custom-tiles) to get some ideas.

Comment: Ive read them and i did not found any answers to my question. what i wanted was to get the data of the existing link connected in the streetview and be able to alter those data(like description) and pass it back and use the altered data..

Comment: as Ive read my own comment i realized that it cant be done(i think, maybe).. i wanted to know how is it that other street view have description on the linkscontrol..